# adding properties to GeoJSON with r

Tags: json, r, geojson

I am trying to prepare some GeoJSON data that I have for displaying on a leaflet map as a choropleth. The problem I have is I can't for the life of me figure out how to add properties to my GeoJSON file. I can get it into R using `fromJSON()` in the `rjson` package, but it ends up being a list of lists and I struggle a bit to get my head around how to append something to a list, let alone dive into a recursive list to append data.

The GeoJSON file I have created can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g1lweiww3trauq0/states.json).

The code I've used to import the data is:

```
library(rjson)
Myjson <- fromJSON(paste(readLines("states.json"), collapse=""))
```

I also have a dataset that I am wanting to add as properties to each of my geometries within the json file.
The structure is:

```
structure(list(State = structure(1:8, .Label = c("ACT", "NSW", "NT", "QLD", "SA", "TAS", "VIC", "WA"), 
                                 class = "factor"), stateincome = c(28959299.93, 392185791.54, 8559477.92, 169039212.3, 61092752.9878, 23695740.28, 298860548.9008, 114231960.463),
               avgstategift = c(48.8204253852119, 64.8584888549168, 45.0472757892964, 53.9720822484215, 50.7162153310643, 53.0923216942408, 62.4033469022953, 50.7348320924839)), 
          row.names = c(NA, -8L), 
          class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), 
          .Names = c("State", "stateincome", "avgstategift"))
```

and it looks like:

```
   State stateincome avgstategift
1:   ACT    28959300     48.82043
2:   NSW   392185792     64.85849
3:    NT     8559478     45.04728
4:   QLD   169039212     53.97208
5:    SA    61092753     50.71622
6:   TAS    23695740     53.09232
7:   VIC   298860549     62.40335
8:    WA   114231960     50.73483
```

I am wanting to add my stateincome an avgstategift columns as properties to my GeoJSON file. My State column will match to the STATE_CODE property in the GeoJSON file. Any assistance on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use `rgdal` >= `1.11` then this is pretty quick work. I've renamed the `State` column to `STATE_CODE` to match what's in the GeoJSON file for "easier" merging:

```
library(rgdal)

states <- readOGR("states.json", "OGRGeoJSON")

dat <- structure(list(STATE_CODE = structure(1:8, .Label = c("ACT", "NSW", "NT", "QLD", "SA", "TAS", "VIC", "WA"), 
                                 class = "factor"), stateincome = c(28959299.93, 392185791.54, 8559477.92, 169039212.3, 61092752.9878, 23695740.28, 298860548.9008, 114231960.463),
               avgstategift = c(48.8204253852119, 64.8584888549168, 45.0472757892964, 53.9720822484215, 50.7162153310643, 53.0923216942408, 62.4033469022953, 50.7348320924839)), 
          row.names = c(NA, -8L), 
          class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), 
          .Names = c("STATE_CODE", "stateincome", "avgstategift"))

states@data <- merge(states@data, dat)
str(states@data)

## 'data.frame': 8 obs. of  6 variables:
##  $ STATE_CODE  : Factor w/ 9 levels "ACT","NSW","NT",..: 1 2 3 5 6 7 8 9
##  $ STE_CODE11  : Factor w/ 9 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 8 1 7 3 4 6 2 5
##  $ STE_NAME11  : Factor w/ 9 levels "Australian Capital Territory",..: 1 2 3 5 6 7 8 9
##  $ ALBERS_SQM  : num  2.36e+09 8.01e+11 1.35e+12 1.73e+12 9.84e+11 ...
##  $ stateincome : num  2.90e+07 3.92e+08 8.56e+06 1.69e+08 6.11e+07 ...
##  $ avgstategift: num  48.8 64.9 45 54 50.7 ...
```

I cover some additional R mapping using GeoJSON files in [this post](http://rud.is/b/2014/09/26/overcoming-d3-cartographic-envy-with-r-ggplot/) but I don't know what more you need to move forward with getting the data into leaflet. If you just need merged data, then `states@data` in this example should get you what you need.